# OWL API and SPARQL

Tags: sparql, owl-api

Is it possible to use SPARQL together with OWL api?
Currently, I'm using SPARQL-DL api, but I would like to use SPARQL instead.

Comment: Short answer, no there isn't any real implementation because SPARQL is an RDF query language. If you want to use SPARQL you have to use Jena or RDF4J

Comment: Yep, seconded. We have a Cunning Plan to allow an implementation to work, but it's only a sketch at the moment. Main problem is that it will be slow.

Answer (score 1):

you can try [ont-api](https://github.com/owlcs/ont-api/wiki/Examples). this is an owl-api over apache-jena. under each OWLOntology there is a jena Graph inside, so it is possible to do anything that is allowed by jena, having OWL-axiom view as well at the same time.